# Does generative model have to be machine learning-based?

Tags: terminology, generative-models

According to Wikipedia,

> Given an observable variable X and a target variable Y, a **generative model** is a statistical model of the joint probability distribution on X × Y, P(X,Y)

However, as far as I know, the term "generative model" is used exclusively for machine learning models, e.g. generative neural networks. But there are also some non-machine learning models that can produce synthetic data, for example [this model](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3148951/) for synthetic ECG signal generation.

Can such non-machine-learning models be called "generative" as well?

If not, what is the correct terminology for them?

Comment: What would a "non-machine-learning model" be?

Comment: @Scortchi basically any mathematical model that is able to produce the "artificial" data. There is, for example, a model for [synthetic ECG signal generation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3148951/), which, in my opinion, could be called "generative".

Comment: So any model that's not "learnt" from data, but that's come up with some other way? (Rather than an ML vs a Trad Stats model.)

Comment: @Scortchi Yes, exactly.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include that clarification?

Comment: Sure. I added this example to the question.

Answer (score 2):

*Generative models* are so called because they suffice to generate synthetic data, but the raison d'être of the term is to distinguish them from *discriminative models* (which don't, having discarded information on the marginal distribution of $X$ by conditioning). So there's no point calling a model "generative" unless you have that distinction in mind—unless the data comprise features/predictors/inputs/... ($X$) that you use to predict labels/responses/outputs/... ($Y$). Nevertheless, insofar as "machine-learning based" doesn't describe every stochastic model that you might use for prediction/classification, the answer to the question in your title is "no"—the provenance of the model isn't germane.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the term generative model is used only for machine learning models that match the above definition. Mainly this is to differentiate them from **discriminative models**, which is also only applicable to machine learning models.

> Can non-machine-learning models that produce data be called
>   "generative" as well?

I don't recall seeing this expression before and would refer to it differently, although I suppose it would be understood anyway.

<s>If we think of a statistical model as an idealized/simplified version of a data generating process, I'd assume it's ability to generate data is inherent and doesn't need to be explicitly expressed.</s>

Edit: I admit that my gut got the better of me on that last paragraph, which I redact after some thought on the matter.

Comment: Please check  [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08539.pdf) out. It lists 'A probability model must describe the generation of the data' as a frequent misconception and uses 'generative model' to describe a type of statistical model, not necessarily machine learning one.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I didn't have time yet to read it in detail. Coming back to my answer after a few days, I removed the last part, which I lack proof for.

Comment: @kao: It's clear in context that that's a quite different use of "generative model", making another distinction: "We need a descriptive model, not necessarily a generative model." I suspect it's rather idiosyncratic: "mechanistic" or "theoretical" (distinguishing from "empirical" or "phenomenological") would be more common.